# Chrome timeout for execution onbeforeunload handler

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I need to implement a feature that checks for changed content before window close and display a predefined warning message if so.
What I did is simply register my handler as follows:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", checkValueChanged, true);
```

In the very handler I initiate a synchronous request (using *jsf.ajax.request()*) to submit all pending data and calculate changes.

The whole solution seems to work pretty well for most cases, but when request takes a little bit longer (300ms?) the browser brutally **kills** the script without waiting for the response.

It happens only for **Chrome** (tested on 48.0.2564.116 m) - FF and IE waits for the request to complete. What`s more when I enable developer tools in Chrome it also works. 
I suspect that this is an intended Chrome behavior based on a fixed timeout for onbeforeunload handlers execution time designed to protect user from various tricks and hacks on some sites (especially in porno ones :)).

My question is: have you ever encountered and handled somehow such situation? Is this "feature" documented somewhere in Chrome documentation or maybe its a bug? If its a feature can it be locally reconfigured or disabled?

I will be grateful for any hints :)